# Making CSS Drop-down Menu Same Width

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, drop-down-menu

I would like to add a drop-down menu to the Our Services menu item on my site.  You can see the development location at http://dev.eimpactweb.com/Contact/.  If you mouseover Our Services, you'll see that the drop-down menu is present, but all of the items are different widths.  How do I make them all the same width?  The source is pretty nasty right now b/c of all of my attempts to make this work, so I apologize for that.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this *long CSS selector* using Firebug gets you your fixed width drop down links:

```
#navbar li ul a {
    width: 120px
}
```

Of course, it will probably be possible to do that more efficiently - but you already know this; it's messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of each  in the drop-down to be a fixed width (e.g. 200px) and that should fix it for you.

e.g.

```
<a href="/Services/Delivery/" style="width: 200px;">LineHaul Delivery</a>
```

or define a class to apply to the  tags in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

The background image is applied to the <a> which scales with the width of the text inside the tag. Apply it to the <li> and you will get a consistent width within the <ul>.